# replace string in template file

Tags: php, templates, preg-replace-callback

I do have that code:

```
ob_start();
include($this->testTpl);
$html = ob_get_clean();
$pattern = '/{{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}}(\r?\n)?/s';
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
    return "<?php htmlspecialchars({$matches[1]}); ?>";
}, $html);
```

and the testTpl file is a php file having this inside:

```
<div class="something">
<ul>
    <li>{{{ $data->something }}}</li>
</ul>
```

the text is replaced but when I echo it what's returned is:

```
<li><!--?php htmlspecialchars($data--->something); ?&gt;</li>
```

I don't have the smallest clue why that's happening... anyone any thoughts? any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's already PHP no need for another set of tags `<?php ?>`

```js
ob_start();
include($this->testTpl);
$html = ob_get_clean();
$pattern = '/{{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}}(\r?\n)?/s';
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
    return htmlspecialchars({$matches[1]});
}, $html);
```

Comment: correct but the thing is the `$data->something` is a var accesible only on the view. any idea how can I do it in a different way?

Comment: what is your intention? the variable `$data->something` needs to be defined in the including script. if you want the template file to echo it why don't you use `<?php echo $data->something; ?>` inside it? why the `{{{ ... }}}` for? are you using a template engine?

Comment: I want to do something similar to a template engine to parse the file before being displayed.  have a look on what I've done below to have a better understanding. I don't know however if it is any other way to not being necessary to write the file on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I ended by doing that:

```
$html = file_get_contents($this->testTpl);
$pattern = '/{{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}}(\r?\n)?/s';
$output = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
    return "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($matches[1]); ?>";
}, $html);
file_put_contents(sys_get_temp_dir().'/temp.php', $output);
include(sys_get_temp_dir().'/temp.php');
```

in this way, the newly created file will be rendered correctly. If anyone has any other idea how to do it without writing the file physically on the /tmp folder...

Comment: you can use `eval($output); ` instead of physically writing to temp. until a better solution is found

Comment: thanks! I completely forgot about `eval`. I'll save it on the disk anyway for caching purposes.